# Многопоточный python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, мне нужно реализовать задачу по распораллеливанию в сфере машинного обучения. Что я по сути имею - есть несколько детектированных областей - их количество от 0 да 5, на этих областях требуется запустить обученных классификатор, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Что-то пробовали использовать? Попробуйте библиотеку [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html), например. Большой обзор библиотек для ParallelProcessing [здесь](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).

Comment: Забыл сказать, что эти области выделяются в real-time, пока ничего толком не пытался сделать, только треды пускал, но предикт на областях происходит за разное время + там приплетен openCV

Comment: Вопрос слишком обширный. Есть ли у вас конкретная проблема?